# Access Update Query: Doesn't update some rows

Tags: sql, ms-access, sql-update

I have a simple Update Query on Access using the tables *Client* and *New Status*.

- *Client* is a table with the information of each client, including the total amount they have spent, and their current status.
- *New Status* is a table that lists the new status of each client every month.

Each month I append the status of the clients on to a the *New Status* table, I don not remove the old records. The old status remains in the table in case this needs to be tracked back.

Every month I run an update query to update the information on the *Client* table to reflect the new information if any.

This update used to work until two months ago. It stopped updating some of the rows. I did verify that both tables contain the corresponding File IDs, and the purchase table does not contain duplicates.

Here is my query:

```
UPDATE Client INNER JOIN New Status 
ON Client.[File ID] = [New Status].[File ID] 
SET Client.[Client Status] = [New Status].[Client Status], 
    [Client].[Added] = [New Status].[Added], 
    Client.[Paid] = [New Status].[Paid], 
    Client.[removed] = [New Status].[removed], 
    Client.[complete] = [New Status].[complete];
```

Please help!

Comment: I just noticed that! Thank you @Uueerdo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you state that:

> Each month I append the status of the clients on to a the New Status table, I don not remove the old records. The old status remains in the table in case this needs to be tracked back.

There would seem to be a one-to-many relationship between the records in the `Client` table and those in the `New Status` table.

As such, since the `UPDATE` query will join each `Client` record to potentially **several** `New Status` records, the `Client` record will be updated to the values held by the last `New Status` record encountered when the records are joined, which will not necessarily be the latest record added to the `New Status` table.

If the above is correct, I would suggest including a datetime field within the `New Status` table which stores the date corresponding to when such status was appended, and then filtering the `UPDATE` query to use only the most recent month's records, e.g. something along the lines of:

```
UPDATE 
    Client INNER JOIN [New Status] ON Client.[File ID] = [New Status].[File ID] 
SET 
    Client.[Client Status] = [New Status].[Client Status],
    Client.[Added] = [New Status].[Added], 
    Client.[Paid] = [New Status].[Paid],
    Client.[removed] = [New Status].[removed], 
    Client.[complete] = [New Status].[complete]
WHERE
    [New Status].[Updated] >= DateSerial(Year(Date()), Month(Date()), 1)
```

Alternatively, if your `New Status` table has an auto-incrementing ID field, you could try the following which uses a correlated subquery to select the record with the greatest ID value to use for the update:

```
update 
    client c inner join [new status] n on c.[file id] = n.[file id] 
set 
    c.[client status] = n.[client status],
    c.[added] = n.[added], 
    c.[paid] = n.[paid],
    c.[removed] = n.[removed], 
    c.[complete] = n.[complete]
where not exists 
    (select 1 from [new status] m where m.[file id] = n.[file id] and m.id > n.id)
```

Comment: That's what I was thinking too, does that mean that I should delete the old records? If that's the case I'm wondering why it worked before.

Comment: I see, that makes sense. How can I fix this? :(

Comment: Does your existing `New Status` table contain a field determining the age of the record (i.e. how can you determine which are 'old' records?)

Comment: It does have an ID column that's set to Auto Number, would that help?

Comment: What does the c. and n. do??

Comment: @Michelle They are aliases to allow me to (a) save typing and (b) refer to the same table more than once.